# How to make nested and, or and like in elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch

I need to do as this sentence sql in elasticsearch but not run me

```
select * from user where (name like '%juan%') and position = 2 and catid     in (4,3,76453,345,345,345345,345) and prof = 9
```

This is one of the examples I've used

```
{
"size": 25,
"query":
{
    "filtered":
    {
        "filter":
        {
            "and":
            [
                { "term": { "user":"juan" } },
                { "term": { "position":"2" } },

                {
                    "or":
                    [
                        { "term": { "catid":"4" } },
                        { "term": { "catid":"3" } }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Other :

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {

        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [ 
{
 "bool": {
                        "should": [{
                            "term": {
                                "name": "juan" 

                            } 
                        }]
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [{
                            "term": {
                                "position": "2"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }

                ]
            }, 
            "or":
            [
                { "term": { "catid":"4" } },
                { "term": { "catid":"3" } }
            ]                           
        }       



    }
},
"size": 1000
}
```

I really need to search for word and with many variables , here I do not put all but given time are at least 10 more ..

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: The version is 2.3.1 , I install now

Answer (score 0):

The filters were removed in version 2.0 of Elasticsearch and you have to use the queries instead. If you want to filter, you have two options now:

- Use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with filter clause (equivalent to a filtered query containing scoring)
- Use [constant_score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) (equivalent to a filtered query without scoring)

Moreover, you should avoid *and* and *or* queries, as they are deprecated and will be removed soon.

Regarding your SQL query, I'd translate it like that:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": { "user": "juan" }
            },
            {
              "term": { "position":"2" }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "catid": [4,3,76453,345]  
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Please note that term-query do exact matches on your fields! If e.g. your user field contains names containing of multiple words. The term-query won't return the expected result. In this case, you should use the [match-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Comment: Wow I have the version 1.1.1 ... I 'm surprised to have this version

Comment: Ok, so do you need also a ES 1.x solution or do you upgrade to ES 2.x anyway?

Comment: Right now we can not update because this solution now in production would need to 1. * and go looking to update on the development server

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work

```
{
"query": {
       "filtered": { 

        "filter": { 
           "bool": {
              "must": [
                { 
                  "numeric_range": {"stocktotal": {"gte": 2,"lte": 99999999999}}
                } 
                ,
                {
                  "term": { "cat_name":"limpiadoasabarra_derechabarra_derechaapulidoras__de__superficies" }
                },
                {"terms": {"supplier_id": [8634, 916]}}
              ]  

       }             
   }
},  
"size" : 1000,
"aggs" : {
    "etiquetas" : {"terms" : { "field" : "supplier_name" }, "size" : 20 },
    "nombre_familia" : {"terms" : { "field" : "nombre_familia", "size" : 20 }},
    "nombre_subfamilia" : {"terms" : { "field" : "nombre_subfamilia", "size" : 20 }},
    "cat_name" : {"terms" : { "field" : "cat_name" }, "size" : 20}

}
}
```